# Node & Docker, can't run scripts after installing Node modules

Tags: node.js, docker

Really struggling to identify the issue here. I'm attempting to containerize a WordPress site on my workstation for dev. purposes. (Disclaimer: somewhat new to Docker, currently using it on a few Laravel projects for the same purpose but have not yet integrated it in production).

Here is the related portion of my `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: "3"

services:
  ...
  npm:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./docker/node/Dockerfile
    container_name: npm
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/html
      - /var/www/html/docker/
    working_dir: /var/www/html/wp-content/themes/my-cust-theme
    depends_on:
      - wordpress
    entrypoint: ["npm", "--no-bin-links"]
    networks:
      - wp-net
  ...

networks:
  wp-net:
```

Here is the content of the related Dockerfile, (I had more in here, but in an effort to debug it's been reduced down to this):

```
FROM node:12.17.0-alpine3.9
RUN apk --update --no-cache --virtual build-dependencies add \
  git \ 
  libtool \
  python2 \
  nasm \
  libpng-dev \
  autoconf \
  gcc \
  g++ \
  automake \
  make
```

I know that a multi-stage build is preferable here, or the other methods mentioned [here](https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/blob/master/docs/BestPractices.md#node-gyp-alpine). Just trying to get the Node build scripts functioning before I optimize my containers.

After building containers with:

```
docker-compose up -d --build
```

I run:

```
docker-compose run --rm npm install
```

And the packages appear to install successfully. In fact, post-install running `docker-compose run --rm npm list --depth 0` gives me the expected output. I can see all of the packages in my `package.json` have been installed.

The scripts for my project are the following:

```
"scripts": {
    "debug": " webpack-dev-server --config webpack.dev.js",
    "dev": "webpack-dashboard -- webpack-dev-server --config webpack.dev.js",
    "production": "NODE_ENV=production npx webpack --config webpack.prod.js --progress --hide-modules"
  }
```

What I'm completely lost on at this point is:
If I run

```
docker-compose run --rm npm run dev
```

The output looks something like:

```
Creating some-new-wp-site_npm_run ... done

> some-new-wp-site@1.0.0 dev /var/www/html/wp-content/themes/my-cust-theme
> webpack-dashboard -- webpack-dev-server --config webpack.dev.js

sh: webpack-dashboard: not found
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! some-new-wp-site@1.0.0 dev: `webpack-dashboard -- webpack-dev-server --config webpack.dev.js`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the some-new-wp-site@1.0.0 dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2021-01-23T15_51_28_095Z-debug
```

I've attempted running `docker-compose down -v --rmi all` and repeating this process and it produced identical results.

Comment: It looks like you're missing the parts of the Dockerfile that `COPY` the application code in and `RUN` the build sequence.  Is what you've included here the whole thing?

Comment: I might be mistaken but arent the `volumes` declared in `docker-compose.yml` taking care of that? If not, I don't know how/why `docker-compose run --rm npm list --depth 0` would even return anything/everything that's included in my `package.json`.

Comment: If you're bind-mounting host content on to an unspecialized Node container, running Node directly on the host without Docker will probably be a much more convenient setup for day-to-day development.

Comment: I can see how it would be convenient. But it will not be developed solely on one machine and I don't want the host's version of Node to be a factor, this is in an effort to circumvent the need for nvm. I will try the method you've eluded to in your original comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

without the `npm err log` i can only guess where the problem is.
probably the npm-cli is not able find the `webpack-dashboard` and `webpack-dev-server` command because it is not installed globally.

try to add the `webpack-dashboard` and `webpack-dev-server` to your scripts inside the package.json.

```js
"scripts": {
    ... your scripts,
    "webpack-dashboard": "webpack-dashboard",
    "webpack-dev-server": "webpack-dev-server"
  }
```

Comment: If installed locally in my case, `/var/www/html/wp-content/themes/my-cust-theme/node_modules`, wouldn't it run from there?

Comment: yes, you could run the module directly by specifing the path of the module inside your scripts, but i highly recommend the way of adding `webpack-dashboard` alias to your scripts! if the path changes due changes of the module you'll get huge issues.
check on my solution and let me know if it works.

Comment: Maybe I missed something ... But this didn't seem to work. I installed globally, added the alias, re-ran script, got the same error.

Comment: does this error also happen when you run `npm run debug` ?
if so additionally add `"webpack-dev-server": "webpack-dev-server" `to your package.json and try again the `npm run dev`command

Comment: Tried that, not working. Also, worth mentioning that it's still saying that `webpack-dashboard: not found`.

Comment: okay, try to install webpack-dashboard globally with npm i -g. if this fixes your error, try to figure out if the `node_modules` folder is present in your working_dir and it has the right accessrights.
another issue can be the bind mounting your working_dir inside the container, which can lead to problems with npm symlinks. try a copystep of your workdir.

Comment: I had already attempted installing globally when you mentioned it in your answer.

Comment: try to execute webpack-dashboard as npx command if this is not working, get rid of your bind volume and copy your workdir into the container with a copy step. if nothing of this works, please provide a npm log in your question